# NuxtJS router push does not work correctly in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

In my application I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page after changing the password.
I'm using Nuxt v2.12.2, with Axios 5.3.6.

My change password route is similar to this one

`http://localhost:3000/password?email=some@email.com&code=b81f9412-1600-4fd2-aea2-70e97a6a853b`

After setting up the password and clicking on the button, the FE performs this call to the BE

```
this.$axios
        .post(
          '/password',
          {
            password: this.page.password
          },
          {
            headers: { 'X-Client': 'web-local' },
            params: this.params
          }
        )
        .then((resp) => {
          this.$toast.success(this.$t('pages.password.toast.success'))
          this.$router.push( { path: '/login' } )
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response.status === 409) {
            this.$toast.error(this.$t('pages.password.toast.err409'))
          }
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch('loading/stopLoading')
        })
    }
```

I've tried to debug: the flow correctly reaches the .then branch and executes the this.$router.push command, but it seems it works only once. If I reload the same page with the same link, it doesn't work and remains stuck in the change password page.

As this behaviour is a bit weird, I've recorded a small video to show you what happens

https://youtu.be/j3s6P3jhVW4

No log is written in the browser console nor in the nuxt log.

As I'm not an expert in VueJS and Nuxt, it might be that I'm doing some very dumb error, or I missed to give some important info, so pls ask in case I can give further details :)

Comment: oh, I forgot to say... it seems like it is working correctly in Safari

Comment: That should not be browser depend on any means. Maybe the `finally` is the issue here, I'd use `async/await` syntax overall. `$router.push` is async too. Also, where do you run your axios, in a special hook? Are you using SSG/SSR? Feel free to share your `nuxt.config.js` file. In the second case (when it doesn't work), if you click the button do you still see something in your network tab? In which route are you when clicking on it (routes tab in your Vue devtools)? Can you reproduce the same navigation issue (no HTTP call + toaster) on another brand new page?